# Why does type="email" break my buttons?

Tags: javascript, angular

When I have my email field on a form defined this way:

```
<div style="padding-top: 1em">
  <div class="fieldLabel">
    <legend>Email Address</legend>
  </div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.email" type="email" style="width: 20em;" name="email" />
</div>
```

Buttons further down the page stop getting click events when the users touches or fills out the email field. If I remove the `type="email"` from my `<input />` tag the buttons continue to work but leaving the `type="email"` in there breaks my buttons.

Here is the code for my button:

```
<input type="button" value=" + " (click)="onPlusElectedPosition()">
```

This is all code from an existing Angular app that I am taking over. And I am new to Angular so I have no doubt that I am missing something simple.

Amy asked for code for my button, so here it is:

```
  onPlusElectedPosition() {
    var newPosition:AlumniRole = new AlumniRole();
    if(isNullOrUndefined(this.surveyFormData.electedPositions)) {
      this.surveyFormData.electedPositions = new Array(0);
    }
    this.surveyFormData.electedPositions.push(newPosition);
  }
```

So the form I am working on is rather long which is why I did not post the whole thing initially.  Keep reading for my full source code:

```
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1>
        Community Outreach
      </h1>
      <p>
        <span class="carolinaBlue">Purpose:</span> To quantify the UNC School of Law's <span class="carolinaBlue">
          Legacy
          of Leadership
        </span> via Carolina Law alumni's stories of service, volunteerism, and leadership across the state
        and nation. Information gathered will be utilized in a variety of Carolina Law communnications/marketing pieces (for instance,
        an online presence with interactive maps) designed to illustrate Carolina Law alumni's leadership in the communities
        where they live and work.
      </p>
      <form #ofd="ngForm">
        <h2>Personal Information</h2>
        <fieldset>
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 1em;">
              <legend>First Name</legend><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.firstName" name="firstName" type="text" style="width: 20em;" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 1em;"><legend>Middle Name</legend><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.middleInitial" name="middleInitial" type="text" style="display: inline-block; width: 20em; " /></div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 1em;"><legend>Last Name</legend><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.lastName" name="lastName" type="text" style=" display: inline-block; width: 20em;" /></div>
          </div>
          <div style="padding-top: 1em" >
            <div class="fieldLabel">
              <legend>UNC Law Class Year</legend>
            </div>
            <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.classYear" name="GraduationYear" min="1960" max="2019" style="width: 6em;" placeholder="YYYY" />
          </div>

          <div style="padding-top: 1em"><div class="fieldLabel"><legend>Home Address</legend></div><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.streetAddress" name="streetAddress" type="text" style="width:30em;" /> </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 1em">
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 12em; padding-right: 1em;">
              <legend>City</legend><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.city" name="City" style="width: 14em;" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 1em;">
              <legend>State</legend><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.state" name="State" style="width: 10em;" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 1em;">
              <legend>ZIP Code</legend><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.postalCode" name="postalCode" style="width: 7em;" />
            </div>
          </div>

 <!-- leaving this next line as is causes my problems, removing the type="email" "fixes" my problem but removes the validation rules -->
          <div style="padding-top: 1em"><div class="fieldLabel"><legend>Email Address</legend></div><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.email" type="email" style="width: 20em;" name="email" /></div>

          <div style="padding-top: 1em"><div class="fieldLabel"><legend>Employer Name, Title</legend></div><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.employerName" name="employerName" type="text" style="width: 24em;" /></div>
          <div style="padding-top: 1em"><div class="fieldLabel"><legend>Practice Area(s)</legend></div><input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.practiceArea" name="practiceArea" type="text" style="width: 24em;" /></div>
          <!-- </div> -->
        </fieldset>
           <h2>Volunteer Leadership Roles</h2>
          <p>Please share your commitment to community leadership by noting all organizations you have voluntarily served below.</p>
          <div *ngFor="let eachRole of surveyFormData.leadershipRoles; let i=index">
            <leadership-role [idx]="i" [role]="eachRole" (deletePosition)="deleteLeadershipRole($event)" #role></leadership-role>
          </div>
          <input type="button" value=" + " (click)="onPlusLeadershipRole()">
          <!-- <h2>Elected Office</h2>
          <p>Please share your commitment to public service by noting all elected positions you have held below.</p> -->
        <h2>Public Service Roles</h2>
        <p>Please share all elected and/or nonelected public service positions you have held, including military service, below.</p>
          <div *ngFor="let eachPosition of surveyFormData.electedPositions; let i=index">
            <elected-position [idx]="i" [role]="eachPosition" (deletePosition)="deleteElectedPosition($event)" #role></elected-position>
          </div>
          <input type="button" value=" + " (click)="onPlusElectedPosition()">

          <h2>Pro Bono Legal Services</h2>
          <p>Please share your commitment to Pro Bono service by noting the hours you commit, and the clients you serve annually.</p>
          <fieldset>
            <input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.proBonoHours" type="radio" name="probono" value="0-25">1-25 hrs<br>
            <input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.proBonoHours" type="radio" name="probono" value="26-50">26-50 hrs<br>
            <input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.proBonoHours" type="radio" name="probono" value="51-100">51-100 hrs<br>
            <input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.proBonoHours" type="radio" name="probono" value="gt100">&gt;100 hrs
            <p class="extraSpace">Please provide a description of the type(s) of pro bono service you engaged in</p>
            <textarea [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.proBonoDescription" name="proBonoDescription" rows="8" cols="60"></textarea>
          </fieldset>

          <h2>Talking to Students About Community Leadership and Public Service</h2>

          <fieldset>
            <p>
              <input [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.checkedTalkToStudents" type="checkbox" name="mentoring">
              Please check this box if you are willing to speak to Carolina Law 3L students about how to get
              involved in public service and what it means to be a leader in your community.
            </p>
          </fieldset>
          <!-- removed per Matt Marvin and Adam Stiffler on 9/14/2017
          <h2>Other Information and/or Feedback</h2>
          <p>Please share any other information and/or provide feedback you wish to share with the Carolina Law Advancement Office</p>
          <textarea [(ngModel)]="surveyFormData.feedback" name="feedback" rows="8" cols="60"></textarea>
          -->
          <div><button class="extraSpace" type="button" value="Send" (click)="onProcessForm()">Send</button></div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: The code for the buttons that break is probably relevant.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, I know it can keep certain state changes of email fields from Angular's detection. Have you tried multiple browsers?

Comment: I have not tried other browsers yet, but I will.

Comment: @Amy I have updated my post with code for the button's click event.  I had left it off because of my observation that the behavior changes depending on the existence of the `type="email"`

Comment: Silly question, is `type` a reserved word?  Looks like not: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah, see here:  https://angular.io/api/forms/EmailValidator

Comment: can you show your full template code?

Comment: @amal I have just posted the full code per your request.

Comment: Couple of things to try: what if you use `<button>` instead of `<input type="button">`? Also, is it not clickable when the email input has an invalid email format address, or empty, or valid address, or not dependent on its value at all? Does anything change if you use `novalidate` on the `<form #ofd="ngForm" novalidate>` ?

Comment: @amal Thanks for the pointers.  I will try them soon but something else has come up so I have to tackle that first.